# POST Request failing due to GET request not allowed

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a WebMethod in my code behind I'm calling via AJAX. The method works when using a GET request but I'd prefer to use POST and I'd also like to know why this doesn't work and/or what I'm doing wrong.

**JavaScript**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/HelloWorld",
            method: "POST",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#test1").html(data.d);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $("#errOutput").text("ERROR: " + err.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

**C#**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=false)]
    public static string HelloWorld() 
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
```

**Error**

```
Message:
"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027HelloWorld\u0027 using a 
GET request, which is not allowed.",

StackTrace:
"at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData 
methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n 
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext 
context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",

ExceptionType:"System.InvalidOperationException"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at some [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) I think you're using the wrong property. I suspect this:

```
method: "POST"
```

should be

```
type: "POST"
```

`method` feels like the more sensible name to me too, but there we go...

(Disclaimer: I've never used jQuery myself... this answer is purely based on the docs.)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks, Jon!